# After flash player update, videos speeds up on YouTube

Tags: 12.04, sound, updates, video, flash

As stated in the title, the videos which I was watching with normal speed, now I see with x2 the speed or even more.

I was so excited that there was a Flash Player update and now (like always) it doesn't work properly. I tried reinstalling Flash but it didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Firefox:**

I had same issue. Follow these steps for glory:

Completely uninstall flash plugins:

```
sudo apt-get purge lightspark swfdec-mozilla mozilla-plugin-gnash adobe-flashplugin flashplugin-nonfree flashplugin-installer
```

`rm -f /home/**/.mozilla/plugins/*flash*so`

`rm -rf /home/**/.wine/dosdevices/c:/windows/system32/Macromed/Flash`

`sudo rm -f /usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins/libflashplayer.so`

Install flash replacement:

`sudo apt-get install mozilla-plugin-gnash`

Restart your browser and have fun.

**Chrome:**

`killall pulseaudio`

`pulseaudio`

Comment: Will this work with Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me with videos: very fast playback and no sound.
The problem was that I had selected the wrong audio output (though I didn't change it).
So, flash was trying to play audio through my graphics card hdmi output, I chose the other output device and everything worked fine. Make sure this is not your case.

Comment: I have sound but it's sped up like video. Now problem solved

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Just one more info for newbie like me: you can change the output device using 'pavucontrol'